# Split RDD into n parts in pySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I want to split an RDD into n-parts of equal length using Pyspark

If the RDD is something like

```
data = range(0,20)
d_rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
d_rdd.glom().collect()
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]]
```

I want set of any two random numbers together, like

```
[[0,4],[6,11],[5,18],[3,14],[17,9],[12,8],[2,10],[1,15],[13,19],[7,16]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two methods:

**set partition num when using *parallelize*, and use function *distinct()***

```
data = range(0,20)
d_rdd = sc.parallelize(data, 10).distinct()
d_rdd.glom().collect()
```

**using *repartition()* and *distinct()***

```
data = range(0,20)
d_rdd = sc.parallelize(data).repartition(10).distinct()
d_rdd.glom().collect()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried the same, it seems to me that, I was not getting the exact number of partitions. The o/p is like
    [[18, 19], [0, 1], [12, 13], [8, 9], [], [6, 7, 16, 17], [2, 3], [14, 15], [10, 11], [4, 5]]
If you can see, there is a partition with four elements, and one partition with no element. Is it possible to use partitionBy to get the desired result.

Comment: add distinct() and have a try